# In Tableau, what's the difference between drag and drag with command?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I feel like that drag = cut & paste, drag with command = copy & paste. Is that correct?

Comment: what do you want to know? please say it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that "simple" dragging an element from a place to another (let's say from shape to color, or from rows to columns) produce a sort of cut&paste in terms of "cut from original position and pase in final position", yes it's correct.

In the same way, holding Command (in Mac OS) or Ctrl (in Windows), will duplicate your element from its position to the final position.
This is something similar to copy&paste you're referring to.